# Google Sheets Script DriveApp.getFiles() A server error occurred

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

As part of a longer script, I am using the DriveApp.getFiles() function to list the files on my google drive as follows:

```
function logFiles(){
// Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
}
```

Using the debug function the execution stops on the while statement as files is undefined.  The logfile shows:

> Error Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
> bit and try again.
> at logFiles(Duplicate:190:14)

Needless to say the error hasn't magically sorted itself out, but the function WAS working just yesterday.

Steps taken so far is to create a project and deploy the code using the project ID.  I have designated myself and one other as project "Owners" and we are both listed as Test accounts to run the script.

I am only using a free personal google account as this code is attached to a single Google Sheet.  Other functions in the same script are working, so it would seem the permissions are okay; otherwise I would expect a permissions error.

The sample code above is taken straight from the google reference docs and it still doesn't work which seems to eliminate any finger trouble in my code.

Would appreciate any ideas on what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much poking around the Project interface, I have managed to get this working by enabling the Google Drive API and Google Sheets API from the Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard for my project.

I have no idea why this works, but it does.  The script was bound directly to a google sheet located in the same drive that was being searched so by all accounts it should have worked without this step.  But for what it is worth - that was the fix for me.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way:

It will take a lot less time this way and you get your result in column 1 of  the active sheet

```
function logFiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  let fA = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fA.push([files.next()]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,fA.length,1).setValues(fA);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Cooper for the alternative suggestion.  My application case is slightly different, but in any case your code failed for the same reason;  files.hasNext() is undefined.  This is because the result of DriveApp.getFiles() is NULL and this is the problem I was trying to solve.  The error log message was not helpful by referring to a "Server Error" and asking me to try again later.  That said, I have found a solution that works for me below.

Comment: I'm sure it did.  There is no obvious reason why it shouldn't except, (I suspect), something to do with the Google Cloud Project settings.  Whatever the error was, the exception was generic and the steps below with the API seem to have solved it for me.  It is more curious than a curious, curious thing on the planet curious.

If anyone has further info on the error, whether it is an Oauth issue or a function only granted by one or other of the API's I enabled, I would be glad to hear it.