# Google Apps Script DriveApp accesses OWNER's drive - not USER's drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two google accounts, call them User A and User B.

User A has developed a Google Apps Script which is installed as a library in a Google Sheet.  The script automates certain functions such as creating new sheets and making a copy of itself on the user's drive, renamed with the Username and Week name, for example:

```
// copy file
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fileId    = ss.getId();
var newName   = "John Wk 1-22"
var file      = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var newFileId = file.makeCopy(newName).getId();
```

This has been working with no issues with User A.

This Google Sheet is shared by User A to User B who has editor privileges on both the Google Sheet and the installed library script.  Now, if User B runs this script, the copy worksheet appears on the drive belonging to User A, not User B.  After the copy completes, further attempts to interact with the newFileId fail because the new file is not shared with User B from User A's drive.

The workaround is to make a manual copy of the shared file from the sheet drop down menu on User B's own drive and then this makes User B the owner of the copy.  DriveApp will then make futher copies on User B's drive and the script functions normally.

The expected behaviour is that DriveApp will access the Drive belonging to User B when running the shared version from User B's account, but this is not the case.  Does anyone know a way of doing this without having to make a manual copy and change ownership?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method by using `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` to get the user email of the user who ran the script and set it as the new owner of the file that was created on var `newFile = file.makeCopy(newName);`

```
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fileId    = ss.getId();
  var newName   = "John Wk 1-22"
  var file      = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var newFile = file.makeCopy(newName);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); //gets the email address of the user who ran the script
  Logger.log(user);
  var newFileID = newFile.getId()
  newFile.setOwner(user); //Adds user as the owner for the new file that was created.
```

**References:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setowneruser
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

Comment: Thanks for the tip but User B is already an editor.  This doesn't change the behaviour that when User B runs the code, the copy is made in User A's google drive.  The DriveApp function always seems to access the Owner's account, not the User's, regardless of what privileges User B has.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, but you can use `setOwner()` instead of `addEditor()`. Try that first if that would work out for you and I'll edit my answer if that works. It should look something like `newFile.setOwner(userB@domain.com);`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setowneruser

Comment: Correction: newFile.setOwner("userB@domain.com");

Comment: I edited my answer above, this seems to be a better approach to what you want to achieve. Do tell if there are any corrections or misunderstandings so that we can follow along.

Comment: Aha, this looks promising.  Many thanks for the follow-up.  I will try it and report back in due course.

Comment: Not having a lot of success unfortunately, due to permissions.  The execution log for Apps Script says: Error Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

This is rather bizzare as I was testing from the User A (owner) account.  So it is basically saying that User A does not have permission to see its own email address.

Comment: It may be worth my expanding slightly on the permissions issue... as this is not the first time I have run into the Script refusing to run on the Owner (developer) account, without first authorising the script because it is not "verified by Google".  I have had to do this several times and very often after I have made some edits.  Yet the script is "deployed" and registered with a Project ID, so I am at a loss as to why it keeps asking the owner to verify that it trusts itself.

Comment: Am starting to think this may have something to do with the context in which the script is run.  The script is intended to be run from a spreadsheet using an onEdit() trigger to fire off certain actions.  If the script is run directly from the editor it will work.  But if run from the trigger, I keep getting these permissions issues, even if I am running the sheet from the developer account.  Sometimes it works, but sometimes it says I am not authorised.  I might be missing something in the project settings but am rather at a loss to know where to look.

Comment: I read through the documentation and this is what it says:

"The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the user."

Comment: If it would be possible, can you share with me a demo sheet with dummy values just to get a glimpse of the overall script body. I actually think that running these scripts using onEdit() is not sustainable since every edit made on the sheet creates a copy of the sheet which consumes tons of resources. It might be best to create a separate function outside of the onEdit() for this particular script.

Comment: Many thanks Diego.  The script (called AutomateSheets) is included as a Library for the sheet.  The sheet itself includes only a short piece of code to call the library:

`function onMyEdit(e){
  AutomateSheets.onMyEdit(e)
}
function onMyOpen(e){
  AutomateSheets.onMyOpen(e)
}`
The purpose of that code is to forward the call to the library because the library functions simply do not appear in the list available to the installed trigger.

I am happy to share, but I am not entirely sure how to do that securely on this forum. 
 I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The reason the script was installed as a library, btw, (as opposed to a local script) was because Class DriveApp could not access the owner's drive to read or write unless it was deployed as a project with various OAuth permissions defined and, even then, only with the Google Drive API added in the Project settings.

Comment: Reference to the issue raised relating to DriveApp:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398699/google-sheets-script-driveapp-getfiles-a-server-error-occurred/70402701#70402701)

Comment: > I actually think that running these scripts using onEdit() is not sustainable since every edit made on the sheet creates a copy of the sheet which consumes tons of resources.  – Diego Sanchez yesterday

The onEdit() is used only to trigger defined action functions from a single cell drop-down menu using data validation.  This is to allow certain automated tasks to be done from a mobile app.  E.G. entering the text "Start New Week" in a particular cell will call the function copyDoc() which creates a copy of the existing sheet and initialises its values for the next week's data capture.